# Tool to check reformatting Python code does not change meaning

Tags: python, parsing, code-formatting

Is there a tool, or method, to check that given two python files, they will parse identically?

The specific use case I'm thinking of:  I'm currently making a large number of code changes to improve readability.  Many of them (reindenting, removing spaces around `=` in keyword arguments) introduce no changes to the meaning of the code (unless done incorrectly) whatsoever.  I would be able to make such changes more quickly if I could quickly verify that the new code was identical to the old, as far as Python is concerned.

Comment: Why not write structured tests? (unit and regression)

Comment: @John:  That's certainly a reasonable way to go.  But given that reformatting code might introduce hundreds of changes that (if performed as intended) shouldn't change the code meaning, I thought the approach I'm describing could also be useful, particularly since it would detect _any_ unwanted change due to reformatting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `dis.dis()` to dump instructions and comparing or checksumming the outputs?